# Mapping from $R$-module $M$ to underlying ring $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an $R$-module, where $R$ is any ring.

Does there necessarily exist a nontrivial homomorphism $R \to M$? If so, how is this mapping defined?

Comment: Well, there is always the zero mapping.

Comment: Ok sure. I changed my question to reflect this.

Comment: If $M = 0$, this is the only mapping. If $R$ is commutative, you have for any $m \in M$ the homomorphism $r \mapsto rm$.

Comment: The question in your title and the question in the text are different. Do you you want a homomorphism from $R$ to $M$, or from $M$ to $R$?

Comment: Commenting on the question in the post body, one would need a module $M$ not isomorphic to any quotient of $R$. In particular $M$ would have to have socle zero, since all simple $R$ modules appear as quotients of $R$... I can think of modules with trivial socles but I never tried to get them to be totally "$R$ quotientless" before.